# Access virtual freeNAS from other computer in same network

Tags: vmware, osx-mountain-lion, freenas

I am experimenting with the NAS software freeNAS, which I run on my macintosh using VMware. Up to now everything went fine, I have access to the web url provided by freeNAS to configure the virtual NAS and also to have access to the NAS (through AFP). However when I want to do the same on another machine (also macintosh), I can not access the same web url that worked on my original machine (the one that runs the virtual NAS). Does anybody know what the reason for this could be?

Update:
When I look at the network adapter setting of VMWare, it shows that the internet is shared with the mac; it provides Network Address Translation for network traffic from the virtual machine. The NAS itself has the default network configuration. No static links or interfaces or defined. Since I don't exactly know which information you need, I have made some screenshots of the network configuration: 
[image: Network Configuration]
[image: Network Configuration]

The link I used to connect to my NAS is: `http://192.168.181.132/`, which works on the machine that is running the virtual NAS, but not on other machines.

Comment: What networking mode are you using in the VM?  What is the IP configuration of the FreeNAS?  What URL did you use before that worked?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the network adapter of VMWare was not configured correctly. For anyone have a similar problem: you have may not use the internet sharing option of VMWare. Instead you have to select Bridged Networking.